# Trouble rendering of documents with referenced fields on Vue.js mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, vuejs2

Recently, I picked up Vue.js and Mongoose to develop a personal project to mainly track Ingredients' on hand quantities on a certain online game.

[image: App image]

Different dishes require different ingredients. `Lotus Seed - Bird Egg soup, Jewelry Soup` and `Jade Parcels` all require different number of `Lotus Head` as its ingredients.
I update an ingredient's quantity by using `updateOne` on ingredients collection.

Unfortunately, I originally embedded the ingredients on foods / dishes, which I realized problematic
recently, coz literally you just count ingredients what you currently have.

So a food document now looks like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fca4ada32195d5814510242"),
    "foodName" : "Lotus Seed and Bird Egg Soup",
    "onHandQty" : 20,
    "ingredients" : [ 
        "5fca481432195d581451023f", 
        "5fca483932195d5814510240", 
        "5fca48a232195d5814510241"
    ]
}
```

I read about Mongoose's `populate()`, and tested to output one food/dish. Unfortunately there's nothing coming out of `Vue.js` front-end after trying that code.

server/models/Food.js

```
const { Router } = require('express');
const FoodItem = require('../../models/Food');
const IngredientItem = require('../../models/Ingredient');

const router = Router()

router.get('/', async(req, res) =>{
    try {
        const food = await FoodItem.findOne({
            foodName: 'Lotus Seed and Bird Egg Soup'
        }).populate('ingredients').
        exec(function (err, food) {
          if (err) return handleError(err);
          console.log('The food is %s', food.foodName);
        });
        res.send(food);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({
            message: error.message
        })
    }
});

module.exports = router
```

A portion of component where ingredients are rendered

client/src/components/Food.vue

```
<div class="tile is-ancestor">
                    <div class="tile">
                        <div class="tile is-parent">
                            <div class="tile is-child box">
                                <template v-if="food.ingredients">
                                    <div class="ingredients-block">
                                        <p>Ingredients List:</p>
                                        <ul class="ingredients-list">
                                            <li class="row" v-for="ingredient in food.ingredients" :key="ingredient._id">
                                                <div id="ingredient-image-container">
                                                    <img class="image is-64x64" :src="require(`../assets/images/food_inv/${ingredient.imagePath}.png`)" alt="ingredient.ingredientName" :title="ingredient._id">
                                                    {{ingredient.ingredientName}}
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="required-qty-container">
                                                    <!-- <i class="material-icons" id="required-inner-qty">food_bank</i> -->
                                                    Required:
                                                    {{ ingredient.requiredQty }}
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="on-hand-qty-container">
                                                    <p>On Hand:</p>
                                                    <input v-if="ingredient.onHandQty < ingredient.requiredQty" class="input is-danger on-hand-input" type="number" v-model="ingredient.onHandQty" min="0">
                                                    <input v-else class="input is-primary on-hand-input" type="number" v-model="ingredient.onHandQty" min="0">
                                                    <!-- <button class="button is-primary save-button" @click="test({ingredient_id: ingredient._id, onhandqty: ingredient.onHandQty})"><i class="material-icons">save</i></button> -->
                                                    <button class="button is-primary save-button" @click="$emit('update-qtys', {ingredient_id: ingredient._id, onhandqty: ingredient.onHandQty})"><i class="material-icons">save</i></button>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </template>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Whole project on Github: [Food Inventory](https://github.com/citrussilver/Food_Inventory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick Fixes,

- change your food schema's ingredients field from object to array,

```
const foodSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        foodName: String,
        imagePath: String,
        effect: String,
        onHandQty: Number,
        // correct this to array
        ingredients:  [{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Ingredient'
        }]
    }
);
```

- there are 2 ways to call mongoose methods first exec() with callback and second without exec() callback,
- exec with callback that you have used buy need to send response (`res.send(food)` or `res.json(food)`) from inside the exec call function,

```
router.get('/', async(req, res) =>{
    try {
        await FoodItem.find()
            .populate('ingredients')
            .exec(function (err, food) {
                if (err) return handleError(err);
                console.log('The food is %s', food);
                // put response here
                res.json(food);
            });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: error.message })
    }
});
```

- exec without call back

```
router.get('/', async(req, res) =>{
    try {
        const food = await FoodItem.find() 
            .populate('ingredients')
            .exec();
        res.json(food);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: error.message })
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello thanks for the answer. Unfortunately there's no output coming from the component. But temporarily, when the part ```const food = await FoodItem.findOne({ ... })``` is changed to ```const food = await FoodItem.find()``` the food component lists all the food from the database. I'd like to ask if there's something wrong with my code on ```client/src/components/Food.vue``` the part ```<ul class="ingredients-list"><li class="row" v-for="ingredient in food.ingredients" :key="ingredient._id">``` Is dot notation not enough on the v-for part?

Comment: i think you have just added code in client side in your repo, i will check and update you soon.

Comment: i have tested server side code as well after correction i have added answer, so probably there is some problem in client side. i will check and update you.

Comment: Yes, I just saw today the client files are not there so I fixed my local repo to push it. Take your time

Comment: i have tested, the error is only `imagePath` field not found in database, add this field in both collections (food and ingredients), after that error will be resolved.

Comment: Oh, I see, aside from this, there are mismatched names on imagePath also. I really learned a lot on this one. Thanks a million man!